# Problems calling self-written Python package from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I wrote my first Python package in Notepad++ and it ran fine from the command line but having problems running it from Jupyter Notebook. The package/function is saved in Anaconda3.1/Lib/site-packages and seems to load fine but stumbles at the first call to sklearn's train_test_split (which is within my custom function) with the error message:

```
name 'train_test_split' is not defined
```

Within the package that works from the command line, I imported train_test_split() as either ...

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#OR
import sklearn.model_selection as sksel
```

... with corresponding calls to train_test_split() and both work. I also tried putting either import statement inside the function definition when calling from Jupyter notebook but still same error persists. Any suggestions, advice most welcome. Thanks,

Comment: Please add more code that shows the call to `train_test_split`. Have you been able to import other modules in jupyter?

Comment: My apologies, I'd commented out the train_test_split in Jupyter notebook thinking that the package call to train_test_split would be sufficient. Now it works fine. Thanks